# 1С 8.3. Как определить, из-за чего стирается регистр сведений контактная информация?

Tags: 1с

Месяц назад стерся `контактная информация` контрагента, а причину пока найти не удалось (человек 20 пользуется программой). Уже несколько раз так случилось.

Как определить, из-за чего стирается регистр сведений контактная информация? (точнее у конкретного контрагента контактная информация стирается, а у других остается на месте)

*P.S. Вручную никто не удалял*

Comment: 1C на какой базе данных работает? Логи можно в БД посмотреть для уверенности.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проанализировать журнал регистрации;
2. Сделать логирование при записи регистра (модуль набора, событие "ПриЗаписи"). Писать куда-либо и потом анализировать.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь что Контрагент - НЕ перезаписывается все время заново при Обмене из другой базы.